# Continuation of an operator $S\in L(F,\ell^\infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $E$ be a normed vector space, $F\subseteq E$ a subspace and $S\in L(F,\ell^\infty)$. Now I have to show that there exists an operator $T\in L(E,\ell^\infty)$ such that $T|_F=S$ and $\|T\|
=\|S\|$.

A hint was to look at the functionals $l_n:F\rightarrow\mathbb{K},x\mapsto(Sx)_n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

So far I have shown that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $l_n\in F'$ (the dual space of $F$). 
Therefore, by the theorem of Hahn-Banach, there exists $\tilde{l}_n\in E'$ with $\tilde{l}_n|_F=l_n$ and $\|\tilde{l}_n\|=\|l_n\|$.

But now I am stuck and dont know how to construct $T$ from that.

Any hint or advice is appreciated!

EDIT: Could I define $T$ with the $\tilde{l}_n$ as $\tilde{l}_n (x) = (Tx)_n$? Then by the properties of the $\tilde{l}_n$ I have shown that $T$ has to be linear and $T|_F=S$.

Comment: Your edit is on the right track. You say that you've checked that the map $T: x \mapsto (\tilde{l}_n(x))_{n \geq 1}$ is a linear extension of $S$. All that's left is to check that its bounded and that has norm at $\|S\|$ (since its obvious that the norm would be at least $\|S\|$ since $T$ extends $S$). Have you tried doing that?

Comment: Yes i have tried using another version of the Hahn Banach theorem (Theorem 5.1.1 in http://www.math.uni-konstanz.de/~infusino/TVS-WS18-19/Lect12.pdf) and choosing $p(x)=\|S\| \|x\|_\infty$, but I cant seem to figure out

Comment: Good, that means you're really close to being finished. That theorem tells you that $|\tilde{l}_n(x)| \leq \|S\| \cdot \|x\|$ for each $n$ and $x$. This means that $\|Tx\| = \sup_{n \geq 1} |\tilde{l}_n(x)| \leq \sup_{n \geq 1} \|S\| \cdot \|x\| =  \|S\| \cdot \|x\|$. That's all you needed to show.

Comment: Oh great! Would you mind copying your comment or something into an answer so I can agree it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edit, all that remains to show is that $T$ is bounded and $\|T\| = \|S\|$. We know that $\|l_n\| \leq \|S\|$ for each $n$ and since the Hahn-Banach extension of bounded functionals preserves the operator norm, $\|\tilde{l}_n\| \leq \|S\|$ also.

We then get that
$$\|Tx\| = \sup_{n \geq 1} |\tilde{l}_n(x)| \leq \|S\| \cdot \|x\|$$
which implies that $\|T\| \leq \|S\|$ as desired.

It is immediate that $\|T\| \geq \|S\|$ since $T$ extends $S$ and so $\|T\| = \|S\|$.